# Images from sdcard not attached to email message

Tags: android

I am trying to attach a image from my filesystem on my samsung sIII attached to eclipse

The following is the code :

```
String ccs[]={cc.getText().toString()};
        String tos[]={to.getText().toString()};
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, tos);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, ccs);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"my mail");


        i.setType("image/jpeg");
        File ff=new File("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20130609_170758.jpg");
        Uri u=null;
        if(ff.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "file is there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             u=Uri.parse("file:///storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20130609_170758.jpg");
             i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,u);


        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "no such file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mess.getText().toString());
        //i.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(i);
```

I am getting the toast that the file exists but the gmail app fails before showing the screen for sending mail with attachment.
I have also tried Uri.fromFile but that is also not working.
kindly update where i am making mistake.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, **never hardcode paths in Android**. Your `/storage/sdcard0/` will fail on most Android devices, plus for secondary accounts on Android 4.2+ tablets. Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` to find the photo directory on a device.

Second, definitely use `Uri.fromFile()`, rather than re-hardcoding a string representation of a `Uri` and parsing it.

Third, if you are only sending one image, use `ACTION_SEND`, not `ACTION_SEND_MULITPLE`. Conversely, if you want to use `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`, then `EXTRA_TEXT`/`EXTRA_STREAM` need to be `ArrayList` extras, as is [documented for `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE).